# Apply convention to types that derive from an Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a convention that I can add to apply conventions based on an interface.

By having an interface:

```
public interface IAudit
{
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime Created { get; set; }

    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to apply a convention to that to specify what the length of the string columns will be, is required, etc. as apply attribute decorations on the interface are ignored. By creating the interface, I am able to define and interceptor that automatically populates and updates these fields on creation and update. I am however having trouble defining the convention to select the entities that implement this interface and applying it to those. I also want to avoid having to add the attribute manually or by just assuming that if the columns name is `CreatedBy` that it must be for the `IAudit` implementation.

Comment: Do you want to select classes/object those have implemented mentioned interface? if so then you can use reflection to see the particular type has implemented a specific interface or not.

Comment: @Brijesh I guess I could use reflection but I was hoping that I could do it using standard EF functionality and that I just wasn't getting the fluent configuration quite right.